# issue with jar includeAll and migration to spring boot 1.4

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

in our db.changelog-master.yaml we includeAll a path relative to the file location. in sprinboot 1.3.6 everything works fine... moving to 1.4.0 it complains there are no files in the location (inside the jar).. of course this is wrong...

any clue ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: no... i am well aware of what you replied  (thanks for that by the way)... i opened a bug at liquibase i hope they will look into it sooner than later.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Liquibase problem (not Spring Boot). When you updated Spring Boot to 1.4 you've also updated Liquibase from 3.4.2 to 3.5.1

There were always been some issues with `includeAll` functionality. 
Here you can find more information about current includeAll issue: 
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2811

Try to downgrade Liquibase to previous version and watch this issue for possible fixes in next version (3.5.2?)

Here you can find previous issue which was fixed in 3.5.1 and this fix is probably source of your problem:
https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2636

Comment: Even if the issue is closed, I still have the same problem with liquibase 3.5.2, 3.5.3 ( includeAll:db/changelog/sql in a jar file)  when launching integration tests with maven. No problem when launching integrations tests from IDE. I must to downgrade to 3.4.1 or move to use `include` instead of `includeAll`